# How To Print Strings From Python App to a Browser Text-Field within a Flash Game

Tags: python-3.x

I want this small python program to be able to output strings into a text-field within a flash game on Google Chrome. The key press emulations work, however the print function obviously only returns the printed code to console.

I tried a few workarounds using a for loop to push the string values into a .press and .release functions, but (not only is this not optimal code) it (as far as I could tell) can't be done.

```
def click():
    username=textentry.get() 
    time.sleep(2)
    for i in range(1000):
        print(username)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        print(f'{i:03}')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
```

Prints fine to console, and the key presses and releases are working. Only issue is that text doesn't get sent to anything outside the console.

My ideal situation is that you can simply start the program and then click into the text-fields (one for username, the other for the 3-code integer) and it will do the rest for you, running through username-associated 000 ints until it gets the friend code.

This program IS not (and couldn't) guess somebody's password. It's for a harmless flash game called stick empires.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems unsolvable (I could be wrong, but after researching for hours and hours the reoccurring answer is that it can't be done.) But here's a semi-work around:

If you use pynputs .type("") function, you can essentially queue up key presses in your operating system as though you yourself were typing a string out. To do this as I requested above, with the first textfield needing a username to be entered, and the second textfield needing a 3 digit integer (iterating up from 000 to 999 for all possibilities) I had to use two for-loops and call a bunch of functions. It looks pretty ugly but it is functional.

```
    #Click function to run inputs 
def click():
    t = 0; j = 0
    lst = []
    keyboard = Controller()
    username = textentry.get()
    a = len(username)   
    time.sleep(2)
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(a):
            keyboard.press(username[j])
            keyboard.release(username[j])
            j += 1
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        lst.append(f'{i:03}')
        keyboard.type(lst[i])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
        i += 1
        j = 0
```